# Appendices without a number

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices, appendix, unnumbered-sections

Is there a way to just have a single, unnumbered appendix in LaTeX? I have a document that has a single appendix. Therefore, it doesn't really make sense to have appendix numbering.

Right now, I have the following code:

```
\appendix
\appendixpage
\section{}
```

This gives me the following text at the start of my appendix:

[image]

Ideally, I would like my appendix to start with **Appendix** in the same size/format as the `\section{}` command. Is there an easy way to make this happen?

Comment: Could you please add a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Especially the documentclass is of interest here. Do you use any packages that are related to the appendix?

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `\section*{Appendix}` suffice?

Answer (score 3):

You need nothing special, actually. A simple `\section*{Appendix}` would suffice, but the code below suggests other improvements, in case of need.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newcommand{\addappendix}{%
  \section*{\appendixname}% start the appendix
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixname}% add it to the toc
  \counterwithin*{figure}{section}% optional, if you want to reset the figure counter
  \stepcounter{section}% reset counters related to section
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{A}% we want A
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}% optional
}

\begin{document}

\title{A document with a single appendix}
\author{Me}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Another}

\lipsum[4-6]

\addappendix

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\fbox{A figure here}

\caption{This is a figure}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it... you can adapt the elements of the style.  Use `\appendix*` if you want a lone appendix, or use `\appendix` to get a lettered appendix.  In the case of the lone appendix, figures, tables, and equations are numbered with the `A-x` notation.

Because Appendices are sectioned as `\section`, one would use `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` for sectioning within an appendix.  Numbering will appear as `A.1` and `A.1.1`, etc. Further, sectioning within an Appendix is omitted from the table of contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\svaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\newcounter{appndx}

%% Create commands to create an unnumbered (lone) appendix or a series of
%% appendices, as needed
\renewcommand\appendix{%
  \renewcommand\addcontentsline[3]{%
    \def\qtest{##2}%
    \def\qmatch{subsection}%
    \ifx\qmatch\qtest\else%
      \def\qmatch{subsubsection}%
      \ifx\qmatch\qtest\else%
        \svaddcontentsline{##1}{##2}{##3}%
    \fi\fi%
  }%
  \@ifstar{\loneappendix}{\anappendix}%
}

\newcommand\loneappendix[2][p]{
  \def\appendixtitle{\appendixname. #2}
  \appendixformat[#1]{#2}%
}

\newcommand\anappendix[2][p]{
  \def\appendixtitle{\appendixname~\Alph{appndx}. #2}
  \appendixformat[#1]{#2}%
}

\newcommand\appendixformat[2][p]{
  \clearpage
  \refstepcounter{appndx}
  \setcounter{section}{\arabic{appndx}}
  \renewcommand\thesection {\appendixname~\Alph{appndx}.}
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}
  \renewcommand\thesubsection {\Alph{appndx}.\@arabic\c@subsection}
  \setcounter{paragraph}{0}
  \setcounter{subparagraph}{0}
  \setcounter{equation}{0}
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{appndx}-\@arabic\c@figure}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
  \renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{appndx}-\arabic{table}}
  \renewcommand\theequation {\Alph{appndx}-\arabic{equation}}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}\appendixtitle
  \if p#1\vspace*{\fill}\fi
  \theappendix\appendixtitle
  \if p#1\vspace*{\fill}\clearpage\fi
}

\newcommand\theappendix[1]{
  \section*{\centering#1}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\def\blahblah{
blah

\begin{equation}
y = mx + b
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\rule{10ex}{5ex}
\caption{Appendix figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Appendix table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
a & bbb \\
\hline
ccc & d\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}}

\section{Normal Section}

\blahblah

\appendix*{A Lone Appendix}

\blahblah

\appendix{One Appendix of a Multi-Appendix}

\blahblah
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]